# Rust: type reference within trait

Tags: rust, traits, type-parameter

I would like to implement my own generic container, and this is the fragment of a trait I am using:

```
pub trait MyVec
where
    Self: Default + Clone + IntoIterator,
    Self: std::iter::FromIterator<<Self as IntoIterator>::Item>,
{
    fn get(self: &Self, index: usize) -> <Self as IntoIterator>::Item;

    // many other methods are omitted.
}
```

Is it possible to introduce a new computed type variable so that I can avoid typing `<Self as IntoIterator>::Item` everywhere? A simple `type Item = <Self as IntoIterator>::Item` does not work because that is an associated type that could potentially be overridden. Using a type parameter as `MyVec<I>` does not work either as I do not want to implement this trait with different `I` types for the same struct, and it also causes problem when writing generic code later. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can define a `type` in the `trait` as implementors then could customize this type.

But you could introduce a type alias outside the trait:

```
pub type IntoIterItem<T> = <T as IntoIterator>::Item;

pub trait MyVec : 
    Default
    + Clone
    + IntoIterator
    + std::iter::FromIterator<IntoIterItem<Self>>
{
    fn get(self: &Self, index: usize) -> IntoIterItem<Self>;
}
```

Or, as a hack, you could try `MyVec<I>`, but with a default `I`:

```
pub trait MyVec<Item=<Self as IntoIterator>::Item> : 
    Default
    + Clone
    + IntoIterator
    + std::iter::FromIterator<Item>
{
    fn get(self: &Self, index: usize) -> Item;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent suggestions! Both can help, but still not sure which is the best solution for my use case, will need to think about it.